# Where should "/log/cassandra/gc.log" file be on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, cqlsh, logfile

When I try `whereis cassandra` I get:

```
cassandra: /usr/sbin/cassandra /etc/cassandra /usr/share/cassandra
```

And `which cassandra` gives me:

```
/usr/sbin/cassandra
```

But when I try `cqlsh` I get:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Also the following is the result for `cassandra` command:

```
precated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[0.001s][error][logging] Error opening log file '/var/log/cassandra/gc.log': No such file or directory
[0.001s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/var/log/cassandra/gc.log' using options 'filecount=10,filesize=10485760' failed.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc=info,heap*=trace,age*=debug,safepoint=info,promotion*=trace:file=/var/log/cassandra/gc.log:time,uptime,pid,tid,level:filecount=10,filesize=10485760', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

It seems I don't have a `gc.log` file but I don't know where should I create such a file as I have 3 related places shown by trying `whereis cassandra`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed Cassandra as a package, the log files will be created in  `/var/log/cassandra`.

Package installations will automatically create an operating system user called `cassandra` and all data files and logs will be owned by this user. However, if you have accidentally started Cassandra as the `root` user, file ownership on data files and logs (possibly including the directories) will reset to the `root` user and the default `cassandra` user will no longer have permissions.

Check the file and directory permissions on the following:

- `/var/lib/cassandra/*`
- `/var/log/cassandra/*`

If necessary, reset the ownership and permissions back to the `cassandra` user. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you've done an `apt` or `apt-get install`, `/var/log/cassandra` is where Cassandra's logs should be.

> the result for cassandra command

In this case, you shouldn't be running the `cassandra` command.  Try using systemctl instead:

To start:

```
sudo systemctl start cassandra
```

Check if it's running:

```
sudo systemctl status cassandra
```

Note that you can also check if Cassandra is running with:

```
nodetool status
```

I suspect that your user doesn't have permissions to write to `/var/log`, but the Cassandra service (created by `apt[-get] install`) should.